# how to add django-database-size to django project view?

Tags: mysql, django, django-views

I am trying to use django-database-size to display mysql table sizes to django admin page. The project has very limited docs to how to add the view.

Here is the repo: https://github.com/chrisspen/django-database-size

All it mentions about adding the view: Install the appropriate view in /sql (currently only PostgreSQL and MySQL supported).

Comment: After `pip install django-database-size`, my assumption is that you'd have to add it to your settings.py as a member of `INSTALLED_APPS` (likely just "django-database-size"), restart your server and browse to `ip-adress:8000/admin/database_size/`.

Comment: To add to the info from @Shmack , it looks like the app name may just be `database_size` and judging from the scant documentation, you may also need to create a view in your database by running (once, during setup) whichever of the included .sql files matches your DB.  (Side note that SQLite is stubbed out, and the DB functionality used by the MySQL view will return _approximations_ for most storage engines - hopefully good enough for your purposes...)

Answer (score 0):

App name = database_size and you need to create the view based on files in database directory.